# Definition of "a field L algebraic over a field F"

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

My book doesn't seem to give the definition of "a field L is algebraic over a field F ".

So I am guessing the definition of "L is algebraic over F"...

In the study of field extensions, does
**" field L is algebraic over a field F "**
mean the same thing as **"L is an algebraic extension of F"**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Saying that [something] about $L$ happens "over" $F$ is another way to say that [something] is true about the extension $L/F$.

Comment: Thank you. Then does that mean if L is algebraic over F, then L⊆F holds by definition?

Comment: Close, but the other way around: "$L$ is algebraic over $F$" implies that $F \subseteq L$ (or maybe just that there is a specific embedding $F \to L$ we should have in mind).

Comment: oh geez. That bugged me for quite a while. Thanks for these answers and clarifications.@diracdeltafunk I d suggest you implement this in your answer. It makes it even more comprehensible.